# Homotoping a Morse function to put all of the critical points on the boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology

Let $M$ be a connected manifold with boundary and let $f: M \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Morse function (that does not necessarily send the boundary of $M$ to a point).  Is it always possible to homotope $f$ through Morse functions so that all of the critical points are on the boundary of $M$?

My initial thought was that this can not be true since then the interior of $M$ admits a Morse function that does not have any critical points - but there is no problem with that as all open manifolds admit Morse functions without critical points.

Comment: 1. You should assume that $M$ is connected. 2. What does it mean to "homotope $f$"? Do you mean to find a Morse function whose critical points are all on the boundary? (All functions to ${\mathbb R}$ are homotopic to each other.)

Comment: @MoisheCohen Thanks for the suggestions - I edited things.